# checking an input number with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

First, I wanna ask what is the difference between Regex.IsMatch and Regex.Match ?
Second, if I want to figure it out myself where should I go to? I mean, is there any help in c# to see what type does a method accept as input or how does it work at all?!!
Third, I wanna check the input to see if it contains only numbers. 
And last, is there any website out there to give me regular expressions? It is a big story! I cannot memorize all the patterns and syntax!

Please dont try with Int32.TryParse() ! I wanna do it with Regex.

I tried this lines of code below:

```
string input = Int32.Parse(ConsoleReadLine().Trim());
public bool Validation (int myInt)
{
    return Regex.Match(myInt, @"^[0 - 9] *$");
}
```

Comment: `IsMatch` returns a `bool` if your _string_ matches your pattern. `Match` returns an instance of the `Match` class and has `.Success` which is a bool doing the same thing as `IsMatch`. Also, your validation doesn't need Regex if you use `Int32.TryParse` instead. Your sample code won't compile because of the `Match` line being invalid and the `Int32.Parse()` will throw an error if the input is not an integer that can be parsed.

Comment: usually doing a search for what you want followed by the language you're using will get you to the documentation. go to google and search for "regex.match c#" and the first link is the doc (same thing with regex.ismatch).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) is the Windows Documentation for the `Regex` Class. `IsMatch` returns a boolean if the string matches the conditions. `Match` returns an instance of the `RegularExpressions.Match` class. In the above example, you should use the `IsMatch` Method.

Comment: and what is the instance of the Match class?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netframework-4.8